# Making Unity Particles point away from center of emmision?

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles, particle-system

For my game I want to make a particle effect which shoots out little lightnings. For this, I set the Emission Shape to "Circle". The thing is, I can only set a start rotation, meaning half of the particles don't point in the "right" direction. I want the particles on the top and bottom to also point away from the center? Is there a way to do this?
Here's a gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTmk6.jpg

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Comment: @Rob "but if your question generally covers [...] software tools commonly used by programmers [...] then you’re in the right place to ask your question!" What's the problem with my question?

Comment: @allesman - the biggest issue is that you haven't included any of your work (aside from a general mention of what you did). I suggest editing your question to show what you've done so far, to go along with your description. And add as much specific detail as needed. As it stands, it's an animation and a high level problem.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution ist to set the Render Mode to Stretched Billboard, and the Length Scale to 1. This isn't perfect but works for me.